# iOS: Stylesheet/Theme for iOS app

Tags: ios, colors, stylesheet

For one of my apps I currently allow for custom themes if the client makes a request (which they usually do, as it's a branded application). Sometimes this can be as simple as simply changing the colour scheme so I was wondering if there was a way to simplify the process. For example, if I had a class named ColourStyle and I specified its colour property values and then imported it to other classes, could I simply set it up so all I have to do is edit this one class and the others will naturally base their colours on whatever value is set in ColourStyle?

Would this be feasible, or is there a much easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways of doing this is that you adapt the new Appearance API.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

There's a good talk and slides about this if you log in to the apple's developer portal;
Search for advanced ui customization.

Answer (score 3):

Style your apps using a syntax similar to CSS!
https://github.com/tombenner/nui

Answer (score 2):

I created a Swift library that lets you do exactly this, plus it renders your styles live on the Storyboard canvas as a bonus!

https://github.com/daniel-hall/Stylish

Answer (score 1):

In iOS5+ there is the "appearance manager" which gives you global control over appearance qualities of various UI elements.  Here's a tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5

If you need customization beyond what the appearance proxies can provide, you will have to create subclasses of things like UILabel and supply your own methods for customization.  Unfortunately some things like UIButton can't be subclassed simply.  You may have to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

`UIAppearance` is one way to go, but we can achieve different properties of the styling engine (like earlier style application and style composition, etc.) by writing/using something new.

My approach allows to apply styled to your subclasses [like so](https://github.com/werediver/StyleSheet/blob/master/Example/Sources/ViewController.swift):

```
final class TitleLabel: UILabel, TitleFontStyle {}
final class BodyLabel: UILabel, BodyFontStyle, MultilineLabelStyle {}
final class CaptionLabel: UILabel, CaptionFontStyle, MultilineLabelStyle {}
```

where the style-marker protocols are defined [like so](https://github.com/werediver/StyleSheet/blob/master/Example/Sources/AppStyle.swift):

```
protocol TitleFontStyle {}
protocol BodyFontStyle {}
protocol CaptionFontStyle {}
protocol MultilineLabelStyle {}

func appStyle(palette: PaletteProtocol) -> StyleProtocol {
    return StyleSheet(styles: [
        Style<TitleFontStyle, UILabel> { $0.font = palette.fonts.titleFont },
        Style<BodyFontStyle, UILabel> { $0.font = palette.fonts.bodyFont },
        Style<CaptionFontStyle, UILabel> { $0.font = palette.fonts.captionFont },
        Style<MultilineLabelStyle, UILabel> { $0.numberOfLines = 0 }
    ])
}
```

For complete usage example see the [Example](https://github.com/werediver/StyleSheet/tree/master/Example) project.

For implementation details see [`Style.swift`](https://github.com/werediver/StyleSheet/blob/master/Sources/Style.swift) and [`RootStyle.swift`](https://github.com/werediver/StyleSheet/blob/master/Sources/RootStyle.swift).

Try this approach with the [StyleSheet](https://github.com/werediver/StyleSheet) micro-framework (compatible with [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) and CocoaPods!).