# iOS equivalent to a stylesheet?

Tags: ios, styles

- **HTML** has CSS styles e.g. class="styleName"
- **Windows8/XAML** has static style resources e.g. Style="{StaticResource styleName}"
- **Android** has style tags e.g. style="@style/styleName"
- **iOS** has **???**

I'm using the interface builder for iOS in Xcode, how do I start to build up a style set or equivalent to styles? I want the ability to apply '**styles**' to elements and then if I update that style's properties, the changes are applied to all elements that have been given that style. Is this possible in iOS development? **Can someone please enlighten me as to how this is achieved or the equivalent please in iOS development**. I'm very new to iOS development as you can see.

Is it more related to skins or themes? I don't have a clue.

Comment: in iOS , you have to set it on your own. Though you can apply common values via coding

Comment: This question might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811422/ios-stylesheet-theme-for-ios-app

Comment: I'm working on a RubyMotion app, and tried Pixate out for a litte bit. Not sure if it's just for RM, or can be used separately, but it's free now: http://www.pixate.com/

Comment: Any new stuff out for this?

Answer (score 2):

- There's [Appearence](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_the_appearance_api).  You often see this being used for colours, but it also does fonts, sizes, and a few other things.  [Here's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6) another good article from a well known source.
- Additionally, a common way to style/'skin' is by having different sets of background/button/... images.
- You can also style by parameterizing drawing code.  Have a look at the fabulous tool [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com).
- Then, some companies do (part of the) UI in HTML/JavaScript.
- Another thing to mention in this context is [iOS' Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/adoption.html)

Comment: The Appearance proxy is for more than just color, it will do fonts, size and offset as well for some components.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [MarkupKit](https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit). See the section in the README entitled "Template Properties".

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a good API in UIKit for this, unfortunately, but there are third party solutions with various tradeoffs.

I created a library that uses style classes, like CSS, which you can define in code, or inside a JSON file, and then apply to views in your app. As an extra benefit, the library uses `@IBDesignable` to live render your styles inside Storyboards without having to compile the app first to see the results.

https://github.com/daniel-hall/Stylish